# How to find zero elements in a sparse matrix

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix, python-3.6

I know that `scipy.sparse.find(A)` returns 3 arrays I,J,V each of them containing the rows, columns, and values of the nonzero elements respectively.

What i want is a way to do the same (except the V array) for all zero elements without having to iterate through the matrix since its too large.

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.nonzero.html

Comment: this is for all non zero elements.. what i want is all ZERO elements

Comment: I hope you're aware that this doesn't really fit with the whole "sparse" idea. The output you're asking for could take a lot of memory, far more than the input.

Comment: @edouard I believe he wants the *zero* elements... which is weird, since if the original matrix is sparse, the matrix of the positions of the zeros will be a huge dense matrix.

Comment: yes, sorry. my mistake.

Comment: @Bakuriu you are correct zeros are a lot but still better than the whole matrix

Comment: @milouk ... no. The whole point of sparse matrices is that they do *not* store the zeros at all, hence they can handle huge matrices. What you are asking would *force* you to store the same amount of memory as the whole original *dense* matrix would.

Comment: @Bakuriu i understand what you are saying what i was hoping for was a way to get all the rest of the NonZero row and column indices. Even if sparse matrices do not store zeros there could be a way to get all the rest coordinates (which contain zero elements)

Comment: What would you even use this output for? It's a very inefficient way to represent which elements are nonzero.

Comment: @user2357112 to be precise i have a large adjacency matrix (4039 x 4039) and i would like to know which edges do not connect.

Comment: @milouk: The original matrix tells you that, though. Why do you want the particular representation you're asking for?

Comment: @user2357112 i know that the adjacency matrix itself tells me which edges are connected but iterating through a matrix 4000 by 4000 is not a good idea. that is the reason i asked in the first place if there is a way to get the indices of the zero elements without having to iterate through

Comment: What are you going to do with the indices of the zero elements? Iterate through them? Still just as bad an idea. Something else?

Comment: @user2357112 yes iterate through all of them still a bad idea bad still better than iterating the whole matrix

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming you have a scipy sparse array and have imported `find`:

```
from itertools import product
I, J, _= find(your_sparse_array)
nonzero = zip(I, J)
nrows, ncols = your_sparse_array.shape
for a, b in product(range(nrows), range(ncols)):
    if (a,b) not in nonzero: print(a, b)
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a small sparse matrix with 10% sparsity:

```
In [1]: from scipy import sparse
In [2]: M = sparse.random(10,10,.1)
In [3]: M
Out[3]: 
<10x10 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 10 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
```

The 10 nonzero values:

```
In [5]: sparse.find(M)
Out[5]: 
(array([6, 4, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 6, 9, 6], dtype=int32),
 array([1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 8], dtype=int32),
 array([ 0.91828586,  0.29763717,  0.12771201,  0.24986069,  0.14674883,
         0.56018409,  0.28643427,  0.11654358,  0.8784731 ,  0.13253971]))
```

If, out of the 100 elements of the matrix, 10 are nonzero, then 90 elements are zero.  Do you really want the indices of all of those?

`where` or `nonzero` on the dense equivalent gives the same indices:

```
In [6]: A = M.A # dense
In [7]: np.where(A)
Out[7]: 
(array([0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 6, 6, 9], dtype=int32),
 array([4, 3, 4, 3, 3, 2, 1, 4, 8, 5], dtype=int32))
```

And the indices of the 90 zero values:

```
In [8]: np.where(A==0)
Out[8]: 
(array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
        2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5,
        5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,
        7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9], dtype=int32),
 array([0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6,
        7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1,
        2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,
        8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9], dtype=int32))
```

That's 2 arrays of shape (90,), 180 integers, as opposed to the 100 values in the the dense array itself.  If your sparse matrix is too large to convert to dense, it will be too large to produce all the zero indices (assuming reasonable sparsity).

The `print(M)` shows the same triplets as the find.  The attributes of the `coo` format also give the nonzero indices:

```
In [13]: M.row
Out[13]: array([6, 6, 3, 4, 1, 6, 9, 2, 1, 0], dtype=int32)
In [14]: M.col
Out[14]: array([1, 4, 3, 2, 3, 8, 5, 3, 4, 4], dtype=int32)
```

(Sometimes manipulation of a matrix can set values to 0 without removing them from the attributes.  So `find/nonzero` takes an added step to remove those, if any.)

---

We could apply `find` to `M==0` as well - but sparse will give us a warning.

```
In [15]: sparse.find(M==0)
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/compressed.py:213: SparseEfficiencyWarning: Comparing a sparse matrix with 0 using == is inefficient, try using != instead.
  ", try using != instead.", SparseEfficiencyWarning)
```

It's the same thing that I've been warning about - the large size of this set.  The resulting arrays are the same as in Out[8].

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution to find the indices for the zero values:

```
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
csrm_reversed=sparse.csr_matrix((csrm.A==0)*1)
csrm_reversed.nonzero()
```

For example:

```
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
csrm = csr_matrix([[1,2,0],[0,0,3],[4,0,5]])
csrm.nonzero()
```

you will get the nonzero indices:

```
(array([0, 0, 1, 2, 2], dtype=int32), array([0, 1, 2, 0, 2], dtype=int32))
```

and then to find the zero indices:

```
csrm_reversed=sparse.csr_matrix((csrm.A==0)*1)
csrm_reversed.nonzero()
```

you will get:

```
(array([0, 1, 1, 2], dtype=int32), array([2, 0, 1, 1], dtype=int32))
```

The dense format of the matrix is:

```
[[1, 2, 0],
[0, 0, 3],
[4, 0, 5]]
```